# Is there a way to allow a function to accept an indefinite number of arguments?

Tags: php, function, arguments

I have a function that can potentially accept millions of arguments. Currently, I am using an array to insert into it, but I think it would be more friendly to have an indefinite number of arguments. Is this possible?

Comment: If you're curious, the technical name for such a function is ["variadic"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), or is said to have "variable [arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity)". The ["-adic"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-adic) suffix comes from greek-originating terms like monad, dyad, &c. while "arity" arises from the latinate unary, binary, &c. This vocabulary lesson was brought to you by the symbols [λ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and [⊥](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type), and by the number [6'7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quote_notation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`func_get_args()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) is what you're looking for

```
function sumValues() {
   $result = 0;
   foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
      $result += $arg;
   }
   return $result;
}

echo sumValues(1,2,3,4);
```