# making a function with infinite number of arguments

Tags: php, function

I've got this block which is appears over and over again in my code with slight changes, i would like to use a function, but as far as i know when writing a function you set the number of arguments,

the block of code im using is

```
 $type = $xml->response->williamhill->class->type;
    $type_attrib = $type->attributes();
      echo "<h2>".$type_attrib['name']."</h2>";
      echo "<h2>".$type_attrib['url']."</h2>";
```

the main difference is that the first line which drills down through an xml document, it may drill down further, in other places, is that possible to do with a function ?

ie. it may need to look like this in some places :

`$xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market->participant`

Comment: So... why does your function need an infinite number of arguments again?

Comment: [From "Related" to the right.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722642/is-there-a-way-to-allow-a-function-to-accept-an-indefinite-number-of-arguments?rq=1) Although you may be looking at it the wrong way.

Comment: Arbitrary, not infinite! An infinite number would both use up all storage space in existence and take until the heat death of the universe to process.

Comment: Yep, PHP has [just the thing](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) for putting in as many arguments as you please:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use XPath:

```
function get_type_as_html($xml, $path)
{
  $type = $xml->xpath($path)[0]; // check first if node exists would be a good idea
  $type_attrib = $type->attributes();
  return "<h2>".$type_attrib['name']."</h2>" .
         "<h2>".$type_attrib['url']."</h2>";
}
```

Usage:

```
echo get_type_as_html($xml, '/response/williamhill/class/type');
```

Also, if any part of this path is always the same, you can move that part into the function, i.e.

```
$type = $xml->xpath('/response/' . $path);
```

Comment: Side note: generally, functions should not output anything but return instead. This is why I moved `echo` out of the function.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for an infinite number of arguments. The way to do this is with one argument which can vary each time you call the function.

First define the function and have the `$type` variable be a parameter:

```
function output_header($type)
{
    $type_attrib = $type->attributes();
    echo "<h2>".$type_attrib['name']."</h2>";
    echo "<h2>".$type_attrib['url']."</h2>";
}
```

Then you can call the function with whatever `$xml->...` attributes you like.

```
<?php
    output_header($xml->response->williamhill->class->type);
    output_header($xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market->participant);
?>
```